# AWS - Difference between ELB_5XXs and HTTP_5XXs

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elb

In AWS Cloud watch, what is the difference between `ELB_5xx` and `Http_5xx` errors? And then there is also Backend_connection_errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTTP errors served to the user can occur at either the load balancer or target level.

Any metrics that are prefixed with `ELB` originate at the load balancer level, there are many reasons why these can occur. For a `5XX` error it could be a problem with connecting to your targets or could be that the throughput to the load balancer was too high (ELBs scale too based on traffic). More information about these errors are available in the [Troubleshoot your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html) document.

For the `Http_` errors these will be coming from the target itself, essentially your application has returned this HTTP status back to the client. For debugging these you would look in your application logs to identify the root cause.